# I want to extract string after a string till the dot(.) in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

For example

```
set a abc.def.efg.hij.jkl
```

I need string after `def` uptil the next dot (`.`) i.e: `efg`

Could you please help me with that?
Can I get a regex expression?

Answer (score 1):

Here's three regex examples in Tcl:

```
set a abc.def.efg.hij.jkl

# Get next token after "abc.def."
set re1 {^abc\.def\.([^.]*)\.}
if {[regexp $re1 $a match token]} {
    puts "re1: $token"
}

# Get next token after "def."
set re2 {^.*def\.([^.]+)\.}
if {[regexp $re2 $a match token]} {
    puts "re2: $token"
}

# Get next token after the second "dot-separated" token
set re3 {^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.([^.]*)\.}
if {[regexp $re3 $a match token]} {
    puts "re3: $token"
}
```

Note, that `[^.]` matches any non-dot characters, while `\.` matches exaclty the dot character.

Answer (score 0):

With a word-boundary constraint, you can make quite a short RE for this task:

```
set RE {\ydef\.([^.]+)}
if {[regexp $RE $a -> token]} {
    puts "I found a '$token' for you"
}
```

However, in this case we can also use splitting and list searching; some people prefer this approach:

```
set items [split $a "."]
set idx [lsearch -exact -- $items "def"]
if {$idx >= 0} {
    set token [lindex $items [expr {$idx + 1}]]
    puts "I found a '$token' for you"
}
```

Of course, you can use more complex approaches for finding the `def`, depending on your real code…

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the string into a dictionary where every value is the successor of the key string.

```
proc makeSuccessorDict items {
    set result {}
    foreach key $items val [lrange $items 1 end] {
        dict set result $key $val
    }
    return $result
}

set sd [makeSuccessorDict [split $a .]]

% dict get $sd def
efg
% dict get $sd hij
jkl
% dict get $sd jkl
```

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)